# Can't disable PIN login on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login, microsoft-account

As you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZNPe.png) of the account settings, I'm not supposed to be able to enable nor disable the Windows Hello PIN. But when I logged with my Microsoft personal account (so not linked to any organization) it asked me to set one up and I can't disable it now. It doesn't matter if I try to log off the MS account, windows will still ask for a PIN instead of my password and I can't change which one is asked first by default.

I've looked it up and gpedit.msc doesn't work on my computer because apparently Windows 10 Home Edition doesn't come with the Group Policy Editor.

Comment: The new "Home Editions" are very limited and apparently a Microsoft account is now mandatory, something I didn't know until recently because I only use Pro.

Comment: It's more secure to use the PIN feature for login to Windows... The PIN feature supports letters, numbers, and symbols in the PIN and it can be well over 12 characters in length.  This decouples the SSO passphrase from Windows login, allowing you to essentially create an app password for the Windows login.

Comment: "apparently a Microsoft account is now mandatory," - This is not entirely true.  If the system is offline when the Windows 10 Home is installed, the option to create a local account is possible, it's only when the system is online does the option not offered.